# Check if the document exists in a collection with where clause. Firestore/Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to avoid cart duplication, so I want to add an if/else method if a product already exists, I will just increase the quantity instead of uploading the same product. Here's the code that I'm trying but exists is not being defined.

```
Future getDoc() async {
var a = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection("cart")
    .where("id", isEqualTo: 5)
    .get();
if (a.exists) {
 
}
if (!a.exists) {
 
}
```

Update
Thank you so much for esentis it's working, i have one more question on my else quotation. The .data() is not being defined, I'm not really sure how to define the documents data to be honest, I just started flutter 3 days ago. Thank you so much!

```
     Future getDoc() async {
var a = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection("cart")
    .where("id", isEqualTo: 5)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) {
 if (snapshot == null) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {
    "id": 5,
    "price": 119,
    "quantity": quantity1
  };
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("cart")
      .add(data);
} else {
  quantity1 += snapshot.data()['quantity'];
}
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no such record, `a` should be `null` so I guess instead of checking with `exists` method which doesn't exist, you can check whether `a==null`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering quickly to my noob question! I need one more help, I'm not really sure about my else method, I'm not really sure what code should I put if .data() is not working, I think I'm wrong somewhere. Thank you so much!

Comment: Try `snapshot.data.data()`

Comment: `a`, which is a `QuerySnapshot`, is not nullable and does not have a `exists` property. You should instead use `QuerySnapshot.docs` method, which gets a list of documents. If it returns an empty list, means no document found.

Comment: I've managed to solve it by adding a snapshot.docs.forEach() { then inputting the ifelse here}.
 Thank you so much!